# Is there a function in Python to paint over the area between lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

There is a set of vectors and I am plotting them by ax.quiver()

```
for i in range(len(C[:, ])):
    ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, C[i, 0], C[i, 1], C[i, 2], length=math.sqrt(C[i, 0] ** 2 + C[i, 1] ** 2 + C[i, 2] ** 2),
              arrow_length_ratio=0.05, normalize=True)
```

Then I plot linear span as a sum of two:

```
for i in np.arange(len(sigma)):
    for j in np.arange(len(sigma[0, :])):
        if i == 11 or i == 12:
            continue
        if sigma[i, j] != 0:
            count += 1
            if count == 1:
                s = j
            elif count == 2:
                k = j
    count = 0
    ax.quiver(C[s, 0], C[s, 1], C[s, 2], C[k, 0] - C[s, 0], C[k, 1] - C[s, 1], C[k, 2] - C[s, 2],
              length=math.sqrt((C[k, 0] - C[s, 0]) ** 2 + (C[k, 1] - C[s, 1]) ** 2 + (C[k, 2] - C[s, 2]) ** 2),
              normalize=True, arrow_length_ratio=0, color='black')
```

I want to paint the area between lines in polyhedral fan to make surfaces more recognizable.
What I have:

[image]

What I want to get:

[image]

So, the question is which function realises that if it exists. Thank you.

Comment: You can add color to a surface, but you will need to insert the break-lines at the intersections yourself. Without seeing how you're computing / defining the surfaces, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Sure. You are really trying to plot a set of plane segments. Figure those out: matplotlib can plot them for you with a quick google search. The only caveat is that it likely won't compute intersections for you. You will have to do that yourself.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks a lot